# Handling BigInts larger than 64 bits with DataView?

Tags: javascript, dataview

I want to transport BigInt values (along with way more information) over Websockets with packets that are made with DataView.

From [this page of the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setBigInt64), I can see that you can only safely set BigInt values that can fit within 64 bits.

The problem is that I intend my BigInt number to be of a larger value than what can fit in the specified 64 bits limit.

How do I use DataView to set and get BigInt values that are larger than what can fit in these limits?

I could just stringify it and then append it to the buffer I want to send, or just `JSON.stringify()` all the package information and then send that string, but I do not want to do that for reasons that do not need to be told.

What would I need to do to achieve my goal?

Comment: DataView is a .NET class/concept. You may want to include a .NET tag ([.net], [.net6], [.net-core]). Right now, it is unclear to a JavaScript expert what your end goal is.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I want to be able to transport BigInts larger than what 64 bits allow across a websocket without the data that is received being different.

Comment: [Edit] your question. If DataView is not referencing the .NET concept, don't use the tag for it. To serialize BigInts that are larger than 64 bits, you'll need to either use strings or some other mechanism that will require a reviver on the other side.

Comment: gotcha, i got rid of it